# How to connect two LEGO Bricks EV3 by USB using python

Tags: ev3, ev3dev, python

For some project, I have to use 7 motors with ev3 bricks.
So I would like to connect 2 bricks using USB-USB link, and make them communicate, in python.

But I don't know how to do that, I've tried some stuff using serial module, but without any result.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a network connection between two EV3s using USB + ev3dev. Just enable tethering (the "Gadget" checkbox) on one of the EV3s. Connect the USB cable to the USB peripheral port on that brick (the small port next to the output ports) and the host port on the other EV3 (the USB port on the side of the brick).

Then, you could use something like RPyC to remotely control one of the EV3s. Here is an example that explains how to do this from a computer: https://sites.google.com/site/ev3python/learn_ev3_python/rpyc. So just substitute one of the EV3 bricks for the computer.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this for myself. But as far as I know ev3dev does not support EV3 USB daisy chaining.

EV3 serial to EV3 serial over sensor ports should work. e.g. as an example https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/346 and https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/695 
Make your own cable with a wire for ground, and cross-over wires for TX and RX.